# Why Nuget doesn't restore packages from packages.config?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a project with `packages.config` file. As far as I know `packages.config` contains all installed packages in project (package will be in `packages.config` only if I installed it from nuget "store" but not manually (browse->select library)). And if I delete any library from references in solution explorer nuget **must** **restore** these libraries from `packages.config`, right? But my nuget doesn't do it. Why?
Auto-restore activated in settings.
I tried click on my solution->Restore Nuget Packages but output says there is nothing to restore. 
And no, ***I don't need*** Update-Package -Reinstall because it will overwrite older versions.

Comment: Maybe because `nuget` has caching, so it takes packages from the cache...? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: do you build the solution ? `ctrl + shift + b`

Comment: @MerhatPandzharov, yes, still have errors

Comment: I think you shouldn't delete the reference to a library from solution explorer. By doing this, you're removing the reference contained in the project file.
NuGet will restore your packages at build only if you delete them from the "packages" folder of the solution in your disk.

Comment: Manuel is correct. If you have deleted the references using Solution Explorer you have removed them from the project. A NuGet restore will not modify your project. It just puts back any NuGet packages that are missing from your solution's NuGet cache and the machine's NuGet package cache. If you have removed references you would need to use update-package -reinstall to add back the references you removed.

Comment: @MattWard, thank you kindly! I'll use you comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **MattWard** said

> If you have deleted the references using Solution Explorer you have
>   removed them from the project. A NuGet restore will not modify your
>   project. It just puts back any NuGet packages that are missing from
>   your solution's NuGet cache and the machine's NuGet package cache. If
>   you have removed references you would need to use update-package
>   -reinstall to add back the references you removed.

I accept it as an answer.